# Efficient data storage using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm making a website for my music association, and some PDFs should be visible to the users. Now, there are about 200 users, divided in 10 groups (where one user can be in multiple groups), and 30 instruments. For all musical pieces, the database should know what musical piece in which group belongs to which user and instrument.

For example, when I log in, with my username "Jeroen", the database should know that for "MusicalPiece1" in the group "Group1", I need the pdf for "Instrument1" with "Part1".

Note that on a different musical piece, I might play some other instrument, so "Instrument1" and "Part1" can change. Also note that in "Group1" I might play "Instrument1" "Part1" for "MusicalPiece1", but in "Group2" I might play "Instrument2" "Part2" for that same "MusicalPiece1". At last, it should be possible to change data. (Not too hard, but with a complex data storage it might be very hard...)

So, I need an efficient way to store this data through PHP in a MySQL database, because I don't want to wait minutes before the script calculated what PDFs I should get.

EDIT: The idea is that the input values of the script are:

```
Username
Group
Musical piece
```

Now the output (result) should be:

```
Instrument
Part
```

This means that every combination gives a specific instrument and part.

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: I tried to make one big table with columns "User", "Group", "Title", "Instrument", and "Part". But this is not efficient at all, for one musical piece there would be like 60.000 rows...

Comment: You need to normalize your data and separate out the natural entities into separate tables. Link those tables with foreign keys for 1-to-many and 1-to-1 and for many-to-many, use an intermediate link table with foreign keys to both entities. Be sure to study up on indexes. There is no reason to not be able to store millions of rows like this and have sub-second response times.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit and re-applied your changes, see the [revision log](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19742006/revisions) - you overwrote my question improvements. I see this a lot and don't know how it happens; in general, it might be worth refreshing your browser pane prior to making edits.

Answer (score 3):

This is a database design problem. Here are your entities (tables) and a few columns:

- Member (name)
- Group (name)
- Piece (name)
- Instrument (name)

Since a Member can belong to many Groups, you also need another table, which forms a many:many between these two tables.

- GroupMember

Also, it seems that the instrument is determined by the intersection of the Piece with your Group. Thus, the GroupMember table determines your instrument:

- GroupMember (id_member, id_group, id_piece, id_instrument, id_part)

Thus, for a Piece, you can list a number of GroupMembers, where the instrument is determined. This permits your stipulation that being a Member of more than one Group allows you to play a different Instrument per Group. Note also that the Instrument is set in the GroupMember, which allows different Members of that Group to play different Instruments.

Lastly, I would take the view that a GroupMember has a primary key of (id_member, id_group, id_piece), preventing a Member from joining a Group more than once per Piece (regardless of whether they have the same or a different Instrument, and regardless of which Part they are in).

You should now find that, if these relationships correctly model your scenario, that you can use SQL to discover anything you wish from your data.

---

Addendum, from the comments: sometimes these relational problems are semantic. For example, if we say that a Member cannot be a part of a Group more than once per Piece, then how do we deal with a Member wishing to legitimately play in a Group for the same Piece with two Instruments? The solution there *might be* to put them into two Groups, each having the same Piece. This seems to be compatible with the third paragraph of your question. Of course, it depends what a "group" actually means in your real-world scenario.

I'd add that your worries about performance are misplaced. You can tune your database with 40K rows into a very fast thing indeed, usually just with the addition of the correct indexes. However, you are optimising too early: get it working first, and then you can research performance issues afterwards. You're on the right track, in my view.

Comment: What about position (part)?  (Which varies per piece per group per member)

Comment: Good point, I missed that. Re-reading the description, I'm guessing it is determined by GroupMember level again. So, that would be another table (Part) and a foreign key (part_id) in the GroupMember table. @user1938314, does that sound right? What do you think, ebyrob?

Comment: You could see the instrument and the part as a combo.  Generally, the idea is that the combination of the user, grop, and piece gives the instrument and part as result.  I'll add this to the original question, thanks.

Comment: OK, I _think_ mine mostly does all that, just minus the Part. If you have a (Member, Group) duple then you can get the Instrument and all the Pieces that the Member's Groups play. Thus if you specify the tuple (Member, Group, Piece) then you can focus on one table, which links to your PDF. Clarification: is it possible for a Member to appear in a Group more than once? i.e. could they appear once each in the same Group for two different Pieces?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your clarification correctly, but a user can play multiple pieces in one group, yes. Also (maybe you meaned this), it's possible that a user plays multiple instruments for the same group/piece combo. Could you also explain what tables you're making, and what columns they have? I'm not really understanding how you did that.

Comment: OK, that changes the relations slightly: I've moved the foreign key to Piece into the GroupMember table, and made that part of the primary key. Now, a Member may not belong to a Group more than once per Piece. Your second new stipulation (_it's possible that a user plays multiple instruments for the same group/piece combo_) however isn't compatible with your question edit; the tuple (Member, Group, Piece) is meant to lead to (Instrument, Part). Your stipulation here would mean that (Member, Group, Piece, Instrument) leads to (Part), which is different.

Comment: Incidentally, I've not made any tables other than the items you see above: all you need to be concerned about at present is (a) what entities you have, and (b) what primary and foreign keys they have, which sets up their relational properties. You may find creating these in a database helpful to visualise what is going on - you are 90% of the way there!

Comment: Ok, so (a) I don't mind what tables I need, this is the biggest part of the question I guess, because a big table will slow down the searching process. (b) I indeed was asking it wrong. What I meant is that (Member, Group, Piece) leads to (Instrument, Part). What I mean with the second part is that the result (Instrument, Part) could be an array, so (Member, Group, Piece) could lead to both (Instrument1, Part1) and (Instrument2, Part2). There should not be an extra input to prevent this, it's allowed to happen.

Comment: OK, if you could fix your question, that would be good. We need to focus on what the primary key is in MemberGroup. Rather than _the result (Instrument, Part) could be an array_, let's state what returns a single entity, and then your requirements will flow from that. Effectively you want **either** (Member, Group, Piece, Instrument) that leads to Part, or (Member, Group, Piece, Part) that leads to Instrument. Which sounds better? Your earlier requirement of (Member, Group, Piece) will still work: this will return multiple rows of MemberGroup, in which your stated tuple is fixed.

Comment: We could look to Instrument and Part as one "string", it doesn't matter to me, but I think it would make it a bit easier. Furthermore, note that both Instrument and Part are not input values, so let's just take (Member, Group, Piece) as input, and have one output. The problem is just that 200 members * 10 groups * (about) 20 pieces, would result in 40.000 rows in a single table, and this is too much to handle within a subsecond. (Or I'm doing something else wrong)

Comment: It sounds like you're uncertain about your entity relationships in English, so it will be hard for any third party to turn them into definitive relational entities (these are much less forgiving than natural language `;-)`). That said, I am inclined to think that someone has a Part before they play an Instrument. Thus, try implementing my answer, but change the MemberGroup primary key to (Member, Group, Piece, Part). Use InnoDB and set up explicit foreign keys, then try adding some test data to see if everything you want can be expressed.

Comment: Put another way, my above suggestion would prevent a Member appearing in a Group more than once in which they play the same Part for the same Piece, regardless of Instrument. That sounds OK to me, since if the Instrument changed then they would be playing a different Part for this Group and Piece.